# Connecting docker rethinkdb containers with existing rethinkdb and sync

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, rethinkdb, dbmigrate

I am running a docker container for rethinkdb. I want to load data from the existing rethinkdb database(running on a Linux machine) to the containerized rethinkdb empty clusters. I also want all the clusters to SyncUP and load with existing data.

Answer (score 0):

You can export the existing database and import it into the new cluster.

```
rethinkdb dump [options]
```

> Since the backup process uses client drivers, it takes advantage of RethinkDB’s concurrency. While it will use some cluster resources, it won’t lock out any clients, and it can be safely run on a live cluster.

For restore

```
rethinkdb restore filename
```

The other option can be is to mount the `"/data"` directory.

```
  storageClassName: local-storage
  local:
    path: /mnt/disks/ssd1/rethinkdata
```

If you are in using cloud hosting, you can consider another volume option.

[Kubernetes-volumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/)

[rethink-backup](https://rethinkdb.com/docs/backup/)